# Accessibility error not changing inconsistent C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a password manager. I understand that the problem is related to its level of protection. So I did CTRL + F and changed everything to public to be sure but I still have an error message in several places.

```
public class Database
    {
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;
        public Database()
        {

        }
        public async Task Inizialize()
        {
            if (connection is not null)
                return;

            connection = new(Constants.DatabasePath);

            await connection.CreateTableAsync<LoginCredential>();
        } 
        public async Task<List<LoginCredential>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            await Inizialize();
            return await connection.Table<LoginCredential>().ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<int> SaveItemsAsync(LoginCredential item)
        {
            await Inizialize();

            if (item.Id != 0)
            {
                return await connection.UpdateAsync(item);
            }
            else
            {
                return await connection.InsertAsync(item);
            } 
        }
        public async Task<int> DeleteItemsAsync(LoginCredential item)
        {
            await Inizialize();
            return await connection.DeleteAsync(item);
        }
    }
}
```

public partial class LoginCredentialListPage : ContentPage
{
public readonly Database database;

```
public ObservableCollection<LoginCredential> Items { get; set; } = new();

public LoginCredentialListPage(Database database)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.database = database;   

    BindingContext= this;   
}

public override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

    var items = await database.GetItemsAsync();

    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in items)
            Items.Add(item);
    });
}

public async void OnSelectionChanged(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() is not LoginCredential item)
        return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoginCredentialListPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["Item"] = item
        });
}

public async void OnItemAdd(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoginCredentialListPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["Item"] = new LoginCredential()
    });
}
```

}

```
[QueryProperty("Item", "Item")]
public partial class LoginCredentialItemPage : ContentPage
{
    public readonly Database database;

    public LoginCredential Item
    {
        get => BindingContext as LoginCredential;
        set => BindingContext = value;
    }
    public LoginCredentialItemPage(Database database)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.database = database;
    }

    public override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (Item.Id == 0)
        {
            Title = "Ajouter un mot de passe";
        }
        base.OnAppearing(); 
    }

    public async void OnSaveClicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Item.Website))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Site obligatoire", "Veuillez entrer le nom d'un site web pour continuer", "OK");
            return;
        }
        await database.SaveItemsAsync(Item);
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
    }

    public async void OnCancelClicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
    }

    public async void OnDeleteClicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Item.Id == 0)
            return;

        var answer = await DisplayAlert("Alerte", "Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer le mot de passe?", "Oui", "Non");

        if (answer)
        {
            await database.DeleteItemsAsync(Item);
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
        }
        
    }

    public void OnPasswordFocused(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsFocused)
            ((Entry)sender).IsPassword = false;
        else
            ((Entry)sender).IsPassword = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what and where is the error?

Comment: Next to OnAppearing, Item, GetItemsAsync, SaveItemsAsync, DeleteItemsAsync

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: the error is the same everywhere, for the DeleteItemsAsync: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type Login Credential is less accessible than Methode Database.DeleteItemsAsync.(LoginCredential)